# Openshift 4.x Session Token Retrieval Using REST API Calls

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I have a use case that requires the retrieval of 4.x openshift session tokens. This shell command for the 3.11 endpoint works as fine:

```
export TOKEN=$(curl -u user1:test@123 -kI 'https://myose01:8443/oauth/authorize?clientid=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token' | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*")
```

However, Openshift 4.4 seem to have different endpoints and I'm having trouble reproducing the same result. Anyone know what the 4.4 equivalent is?

Using the openshift cli is not an option

Answer (score 0):

First get your Endpoints with this command:

oc get --raw '/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server'

You are looking for: authorization_endpoint

Then add this Header to your request:

-H "X-CSRF-Token: 100"

So if you run:
curl -u user1:test@123 'https://authorization_endpoint_URL/oauth/authorize?clientid=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token' -kI -H "X-CSRF-Token: 100" | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*"

you will get your Token.